# Finding Coefficients of LFSR

Tags: cryptography

I am studying cryptography from Cristof Paar's book. There is a question about LFSR's I have trouble with. I just can't understand one point here. Question is this:

We want to perform an attack on another LFSR-based stream cipher. In order
to process letters, each of the 26 uppercase letters and the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
are represented by a 5-bit vector according to the following mapping:

A -> 0 = 00000
.
.
.
Z -> 25 = 11001
0 -> 26 = 11010
.
.
.
5 -> 31= 11111
(binary)

We happen to know the following facts about the system:

-The degree of the LFSR is m = 6.

-Every message starts with the header WPI

We observe now on the channel the following message (the fourth letter is a zero): j5a0edj2b

2. What are the feedback coefficients of the LFSR? (This one!)

Solution:

[image: Solution]

I can't understand the matrix in this solution where did these numbers come?

Comment: If you just have a tag [cryptography] then I think you may be better off at [http://crypto.stackexchange.com/].

Answer (score 1):

Using WPI, we have plaintext begins with

P=>(10110)(01111)(01000)

Using j5a0edj2b we have the ciphertext

C=>(01001)(11111)(00000)(11010)(00100)(00011)(01001)............

then by addition of P and C in mod 2, the key stream is

S=>(11111)(10000)(01000)....

we find the matrix from key stream

s0=1,s1=1,s2=1,s3=1,s4=1,s5=1,s6=0,s7=0,s8=0,s9=0,s10=0,s11=1 etc

For the matrix

first line.... (s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)

second line....(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6)

third line.....(s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7)

4th            (s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8)

5th            (s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9)

last line      (s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10)

this calulations are given in LFSRs in details